# how to set the value on dynamically created input fields

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).find("input#basicSalary").val(val1);
$(document).find("input#fixedAmount").val(val2);
```

The above code is not working for me.Here I am trying to set the value to dynamically created input field

Comment: maybe you are trying to set the value before the elements are created.Please share the code of how you are creating elements and how you are trying to set it

Comment: Your question is going to require a lot more contextual code. What you have posted on its own will work perfectly if:
1. `input#basicSalary` and `input#fixedAmount` exist in the DOM, and
2. `val1` and `val2` are defined.
Do you have any errors appearing on the console?

Comment: Do your dynamically created fields have `id` attribute values _"basicSalary"_ and _"fixedAmount"_? Do they exist in the document when this code executes? Are they the **only** elements with those `id` values?

Comment: What is console error message?

Comment: Also, your queries can be shortened to `$('#basicSalary')` and `$('#fixedAmount')`. There's no need to use `$(document).find(...)` as that is the default. Specifying the element types in your selectors is also redundant for _id_ queries

Comment: @brk, yeah I am trying to set the value before elements are created. Is there any solution to this. My code too long to send here.

Comment: @Phil, my input fields do not exist in the document when this code is executing.

Comment: no you cannot do that , there must a function which is dynamically creating the elements, so just set the values to the element after they are created

Comment: So what triggers this code to execute? Can it not wait until the elements exist?

Comment: When I click on modify data button at that time I am storing the previous data in 2 variables. After that it opens a select input option when the user selects any one input in the select input field I am appending input field inside that input field I am trying set the previous data in that field.